# Format the Number for display in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to Format the Number in line 37 but I'm not able to print expected output. Basically I'm getting 23 but I'm trying achieve output like this 0023.Please let me know if I'm doing wrong some where in code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure DE_DUP_PROC (Dy_File_Name  in VARCHAR2,
SUPPLIER_CD in varchar2,
EXT_PHARMA_ID in varchar2,
FLAG_VALUE in varchar2,
DE_REC_COUNT out NUMBER) 
   --RETURN NUMBER
AS
    SEQ_NO_SHO Number(38);                          --EEEE
    WYYYYNNN VARCHAR2(250) := 'W2015021';
    YYYYNNN VARCHAR2(10);
    CUR_DATE Date; 
    --De_Rec_Count Number(38) := 3456;
    DE_DUB_OUTPUT_FILE VARCHAR2(100);
    DE_REC_COUNT1 NUMBER(10);



BEGIN

        SQL='SELECT count(*) into DE_REC_COUNT FROM  (SELECT stg.*, row_number() over ( partition BY key_clmns_hash ORDER BY 1 ) AS RN FROM '|| Dy_File_Name ||' stg ) s
        LEFT JOIN ps_pharmacy p ON s.extrnl_pharmacy_id = p.extrnl_pharmacy_id LEFT JOIN ps_rx_hist H ON h.key_clmns_hash = s.key_clmnS_hash
        AND h.rx_dspnsd_dt = s.rx_dspnsd_dt AND s.supplier_pharmacy_cd = h.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD AND s.detl_clmns_hash <> h.detl_clmns_hash WHERE S.RN = 1';

        execute immediate SQL INTO DE_REC_COUNT;

        if DE_REC_COUNT > 0
        then


                YYYYNNN := replace(WYYYYNNN,'W','');

                --SEQ_NO_SHO := FUN_XYZ(SUPPLIER_CD,EXT_PHARMA_ID,YYYYNNN);
                SEQ_NO_SHO := 23;
                SEQ_NO_SHO := to_char(SEQ_NO_SHO,'0999');

                **DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SEQ_NO_SHO);**

                DE_DUB_OUTPUT_FILE := 'LRXIE'||FLAG_VALUE||'10_'||SUPPLIER_CD||'_'||EXT_PHARMA_ID||'_'||WYYYYNNN||'_'||SEQ_NO_SHO||'_'||DE_REC_COUNT1||'.TXT';

                --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DE_DUB_OUTPUT_FILE);


            DE_REC_COUNT :=0;
        else

            DE_REC_COUNT :=1;

        End if;
    --      
END DE_DUP_PROC;
```

Output :-23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `LPAD` function:

```
SEQ_NO_SHO VARCHAR2(38);
SEQ_NO_SHO := '23';
SEQ_NO_SHO := LPAD(SEQ_NO_SHO, 4, '0');
```

**Output:**

```
0023
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use all zeroes in the format mask:

```
begin
    for i in 5 .. 15 loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('-' || to_char (i, '0000'));
    end loop;
end;
```

Result:

```
PL/SQL block executed
- 0005
- 0006
- 0007
- 0008
- 0009
- 0010
- 0011
- 0012
- 0013
- 0014
- 0015
```

Comment: Tom goes into this in more detail here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=format-the-number-for-display